# how to create , store and retrieve the values from hash table in c#?

Tags: c#, hashtable

How to create , store and retrieve the values from hash table in c#?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**Hashtable Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)

```
// Initializes a new hashtable    
Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();

// Adds an item to the hashtable
hTable.Add("Name",  "Jon");

// Loop through all the values in the hashtable
IDictionaryEnumerator enumHtable = hTable.GetEnumerator();
while (enumHtable.MoveNext())
{
    string str = enumHtable.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [C# Hashtable Use, Lookups and
  Examples](http://dotnetperls.com/hashtable)
- [How to work with the HashTable collection in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309357)

'

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable[1] = "One";
hashtable[2] = "Two";
hashtable[13] = "Thirteen";

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
Object k = new Object(); // can be any type of object
Object v = new Object(); // can be any type of object
h[k] = v;
```

If you are working in .Net version 2.0 or above, it can be more useful to use a `Dictionary<K, V>` where you can type the keys and values. Otherwise, you need to cast the values when you get them:

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
Object k = new Object(); // can be any type of object
String v = "My value";
h[k] = v;
String value = (String)h[k];
```